# Unable to log Custom Events through Firebase, but logs the pre-defined events

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to use Firebase for Analytics but I am not able to get anything through custom events on my dashboard. Strangely, all the pre-defined events such as "user_engagement" "app_background" are logged successfully.

I have enabled verbose debugging on Firebase by setting the flag in the build, no event logging is reported through logs nor the console. I have removed the GoogleService-Info.plist and added it again to see if there was wrong about it. But it was giving the same problem. Also, I tried the sample app by google with the same GoogleService-Info.plist and it was working fine there.

Comment: can u share ur code

Comment: generally it might take few hours for events to get reflected in your console

Comment: Yeah, but I have set -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled flag which enables verbose logging and instant reporting in debug console in firebase account, neither the logs on Xcode mentions any custom events logged, nor it appears on console, even after 48 hours